# How can select a column and subtract the minimum number of this column with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select all the value of a column, then subtract all them with the minimum value of this column.

MySQL statement goes like this :

```
select `value`-min(`value`) from `table`
```

However,MySQL return this error message:

```
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list 
contains nonaggregated column 'demo.table.value'; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with a sub-query:

```
select `value`- (select min(`value`) from `table`) 
from `table`
```

Comment: It works ! Could your explain a little why shall I use double `select` ? Thanks.

Comment: MySql will not let you mix an aggregation function and fields without a group by clause. that's why an extra query works - this sub-query is calculated one-time for the whole query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select   
   T.id,
   T.value - min_val 

from table T INNER JOIN ( select id , min(value) as min_val from table group by id) MT on  T.id = MT.id;
```